# Can I create an alias for a package name in R?

Tags: r

Some package names can be quite long, and it is often safer to refer to package objects using the fully qualified name (`long_package_name::package_object`) rather than attaching it using `library(long_package_name)`.

Is there a way to assign an alias `short_name` to the package `long_package_name`, so that you can then use `short_name::package_object`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's mentioned in the duplicate question, but there are a couple of packages such as [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules) which provide Python-like importing that may be leveraged to fit your need.

Comment: @nrussell that would be a worthy answer to add to the other question

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for the support, but unfortunately I don't have the time to write up a proper answer at the moment. Please feel free to take that idea and run with it though.